# Can you shorten an SVG line to make space for an arrow head automatically?

Tags: svg

In SVG, you can define markers that can be placed on the start or end of a line like this:

```xml
<defs>
  <marker 
     id="arrowhead" 
     markerWidth="9" markerHeight="6" 
     refX="9" refY="3" 
     orient="auto" 
     markerUnits="strokeWidth"
  >
    <path d="M0,0 L9,3 L0,6 z" />
  </marker>
</defs>
```

Later, you can use them like this:

```xml
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" strokeWidth="5" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" />
```

However, this approach causes the arrow head and the line to overlap:

[image: example image]

That does not look nice.

Now, we could of course move the arrow head a little further out and shorten the line to compensate for the added length of the arrow head, using some trigonometry to figure out where `x2` and `y2` would need to be shifted. Whenever I would change the length of the arrow head, I would need to re-do those calculations for all lines that use the arrow head to make the tips of the arrow arrive at the same positions.

I have the intuition that, just like SVG is already taking care about the orientation  using `orient="auto"`, there could be a similar device to shorten the line slightly to accommodate for the space of the arrow head. So, my question is:

**Is it possible to make an SVG line shorter than the distance between its coordinates by a fixed length, without moving the coordinates themselves?**

Edit: The linked answer does not solve my question. I know that I can use `refX` and `refY` to move the *marker* -- I'm already doing that, see the code above --, but I want to move the *end of the line below the marker*.

Here's a snippet with a more pronounced example: The red line should end in a black arrow head. Instead, the arrow head is overlaid on top of it, making the red shine through. Now, I *could* make the line a little shorter and use `refX="0"` for the desired effect, but that would require manually calculating the `x2` and `y2` positions. My question is whether there is a built-in feature of SVG that allows me to shorten the line, or whether the only possibility is to shorten the line by changing its end point manually.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 50 10" width="1000" height="200">
<defs>
  <marker 
     id="arrowhead" 
     markerWidth="20" markerHeight="3" 
     refX="20" refY="1.5" 
     orient="auto" 
     markerUnits="strokeWidth"
  >
    <path d="M0,0 L20,1.5 L0,3 z" />
  </marker>
</defs>
<line x1="0" y1="2" x2="25" y2="3" stroke="red" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The duplicate answers are all SVG offers i.e. there is **no** built in function to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question!